# How to attach cookie to request when setting iframe.src (using jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cookies

Using JavaScript/jQuery within a web page, I need to load a different page into an iframe.  I am doing it by finding the iframe using jQuery, and setting its src property, thus:

```
iframe.src = url;
```

Which works in that it displays the page in the iframe, but I need to attach a couple of cookies to that request to get the correct info on the page, and I can't figure out how to do that.

In the spirit of trial and error I tried inserting this line before the above code:

```
$.cookie("MyCookieName", "MyCookieValue");
```

but in Fiddler I see no cookie attached to the request. All the documentation I can find about cookies tells me how to generally get & set the values, but doesn't help explain what I'm doing wrong.

For what it's worth, the page that I'm loading into the iframe is in the same domain as the page hosting this JavaScript code.

How do I attach cookies to that query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I attach cookies to that query?

You can’t “attach” cookies to a simple HTTP request that the browser makes on his own.

> For what it's worth, the page that I'm loading into the iframe is in the same domain as the page hosting this JavaScript code.

Then set the cookie for that domain the normal way – once it’s set, the browser will send it when requesting the iframe URL automatically.

Comment: But it's on the same domain, as I explained.

Comment: I'm afraid my ignorance is showing here - what is "the normal way"?

Comment: @DaveW `$.cookie("MyCookieName", "MyCookieValue");` for example. Are you sure the url you are using is of the same origin as the parent page? same protocol, subdomain, domain, and port?

Comment: Ahah! It's all on my local dev machine at the moment, so the urls are all http://localhost,  but your comment just made me realise - the page with the iframe is running from Visual Studio while I'm debugging it, so is on a different port.  I expect that's the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Cookies don't vary by port.